# Allow user to select notification sound in iOS Notification Settings

Tags: ios, notifications, push-notification

I have an app that is properly posting notifications with the default iOS notification sound.

I would like to allow my users to choose their own sounds. I know I could do this in my app, but I'd rather do it in the Notifications area like one can with the standard Messages app.

I have looked and don't see anything new talking about this. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: So you know how to customize the notification sound, and the issue is that you don't want to handle switching sounds inside the app but instead you would like to handle it in Apple's settings app?

Comment: Yes, that's correct @Artal. I know I could create a settings bundle, but I want to have it in the notification section like the messages app does.

Comment: in that case it is not possible as far as I know... There's nothing you can do to add yourself to Apple's own notification settings, and using your own app's settings bundle won't work either since it can't execute any code or include logic.

Comment: Well that does correspond with what I'm seeing, I was just hoping I was wrong. Thanks for the info.